# sqlite3 output with tabs from one line command

Tags: sqlite

I want to have my sqlite3 output separated by tabs. The -column option does not suit me because separate records with spaces and my values have spaces but no tabs.

If I use interactively sqlite3 I can use `.mode tab`. The one-line command has the option -separator but I don't know how to add a tab there that gets interpreted as a tab not literal (probably with and ASCII code?)

Any suggestions? All the google examples that I found was for interactive sqlite3.

At the moment I am using the brute force approach:

```
sqlite3 -header mydb "select * from table1" | tr \| '\t' > myoutput
```

Comment: I found a way of adding the tab to the -separator option: control-v tab (surounded by single quotes)

Comment: Please, rewrite your self-comment as answer (and accept it after the 2 or so days it will allow you to accept self-answer), so it's obvious that the problem is solved and how for anybody who faces similar problem and comes looking for solution. Thanks.

Comment: @jan, thanks I can put my comment as an answer but the thing is that I don't like this solution (neither the tr one). I have strong opinions about code re-usability and maintainability so I don't like any code that does not differentiate between spaces and tabs explicitly in the command line. I will wait for better solutions at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works on both Linux and Windows:

```
sqlite3 -header -cmd ".mode tabs" mydb "select * from table1"
```

Answer (score 25):

This should work:

```
sqlite3 -separator $'\t' -header mydb "select * from table1"
```

The $ tells your shell to expand to a tab character.

Comment: +1 this is better than my solutions thanks. I will wait a bit for other answers at the moment if you don't mind.

Answer (score 18):

You can directly use `.mode tab` when using sqlite in a shell script (for example) by using a here document like:

```
sqlite3 -header mydb <<EOF
.mode tabs
select * from table1;
EOF
```